# xcode objective-c - avoiding multiple methods with the same name (using 'setEnabled')

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios4, ios5

I'm getting an error in XCode:

multiple methods named 'setEnabled' found with mismatched result, parameter type, or attributes

I'm using the following code within AppDelegate.m:

```
#import "BluetoothManager.h"
Class BluetoothManager = objc_getClass( "BluetoothManager" ) ;
id btCont = [BluetoothManager sharedInstance] ;
[btCont setEnabled:!currentState] ;
```

Comment: Why do you want to do it this way?

Comment: I dunno - I just found some code on Stack that supposedly will allow me to do what I need to do. I'm unfortunately not too skilled in programming with XCode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you're importing `BluetoothManager.h` then you have it resolved at compile-time, adjust the code to say:

```
#import "BluetoothManager.h"
Class BluetoothManagerClass = objc_getClass( "BluetoothManager" );
BluetoothManager *btCont = [BluetoothManagerClass sharedInstance];
[btCont setEnabled:!currentState];
```

are you trying to support a new class, but also run in older iOS?

**in response to Q1:** the "simple" version, if you're not trying to do anything tricky, is to forego the `objc_getClass` which provides dynamic flexibility that is not often needed

```
#import "BluetoothManager.h"
BluetoothManager *btCont = [BluetoothManager sharedInstance];
[btCont setEnabled:!currentState];
```

This assumes:

- The class `BluetoothManager` is declared in "BluetoothManager.h"
- there is a class method declared (and defined) on it `+sharedInstance` (which to follow common Objective-C naming conventions, I would rename to `+sharedBluetoothManager`)
- BluetoothManager declares a method called `-setEnabled:`

Comment: Well, all this app will really do is run on someone's local phone, so no - it doesn't need to support any older versions of iOS - it is an application that allows one touch switching of bluetooth. When I switch your code, I get an error: "use of undeclared identifier 'btCont'" - also is "BluetoothManagerClass" supposed to be "BluetoothManager"

Comment: @bshirly Why do I get a comment that btCont is an undeclared identifier?

Comment: more code would be needed (BluetoothManager header) to guess at that